# Order by a different field on a GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, order-by, group-concatenation

Given the following script:

```
SELECT 
    category AS MODULE,
    acl_roles.name as ROLE_NAME
     ,GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE aclaccess 
            WHEN 89 THEN 'E' 
            WHEN 0 THEN 'N' 
            WHEN -98 THEN 'D' 
            WHEN 90 THEN 'A' 
            WHEN 75 THEN 'O' 
            WHEN -99 THEN 'N' 
        END 
      SEPARATOR ', ') AS DEFAULT_ACCESS_WEB
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE access_override 
        WHEN 89 THEN 'E' 
        WHEN 0 THEN 'N' 
        WHEN -98 THEN 'D' 
        WHEN 90 THEN 'A' 
        WHEN 75 THEN 'O' 
        WHEN -99 THEN 'N' 
        END 
      SEPARATOR ', ') AS OVERRIDE_ACCESS_WEB
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(
        acl_actions.name ORDER BY FIELD(acl_actions.name, "access", "delete", "edit", "export", "import", "list", "view") 
        SEPARATOR ', ') AS ACTION_NAME_ORDER
FROM `acl_roles_actions`
    JOIN `acl_actions` ON acl_actions.id = acl_roles_actions.action_id
    JOIN `acl_roles` ON acl_roles_actions.role_id = acl_roles.id
WHERE `role_id` in ('SOME_HASH', 'ANOTHER_HASH') AND `action_id` IN
 (SELECT `id` FROM `acl_actions` WHERE `category` LIKE '%SOMENAME%')
 GROUP BY ROLE_NAME
 ORDER BY ROLE_NAME, FIELD(acl_actions.name, "access", "delete", "edit", "export", "import", "list", "view")
```

I need to have the `DEFAULT_ACCESS_WEB` and `OVERRIDE_ACCESS_WEB` results adhere to the same ordering as the `ACTION_NAME_ORDER`.

The `ACTION_NAME_ORDER` is appearing in the correct order in the results, but I'm unable to get the same `ORDER BY FIELD(acl_actions.name, "access", "delete", "edit", "export", "import", "list", "view")` working within the first 2 `GROUP_CONCAT`'s.

Do they need to be nested within extra `SELECT`s to have a context of the field I want to order them by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out, I needed to put the `ORDER BY FIELD` after the `END` of the `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    category AS MODULE,
    acl_roles.name as ROLE_NAME
     ,GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE aclaccess
            WHEN 89 THEN 'E'
            WHEN 0 THEN 'N'
            WHEN -98 THEN 'D'
            WHEN 90 THEN 'A'
            WHEN 75 THEN 'O'
            WHEN -99 THEN 'N'
        END ORDER BY FIELD(acl_actions.name, "access", "delete", "edit", "export", "import", "list", "view") 
      SEPARATOR ', ') AS DEFAULT_ACCESS_WEB
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(
        CASE access_override
        WHEN 89 THEN 'E'
        WHEN 0 THEN 'N'
        WHEN -98 THEN 'D'
        WHEN 90 THEN 'A'
        WHEN 75 THEN 'O'
        WHEN -99 THEN 'N'
        END ORDER BY FIELD(acl_actions.name, "access", "delete", "edit", "export", "import", "list", "view") 
      SEPARATOR ', ') AS OVERRIDE_ACCESS_WEB
      ,GROUP_CONCAT(
        acl_actions.name ORDER BY FIELD(acl_actions.name, "access", "delete", "edit", "export", "import", "list", "view")
        SEPARATOR ', ') AS ACTION_NAME_ORDER
FROM `acl_roles_actions`
    JOIN `acl_actions` ON acl_actions.id = acl_roles_actions.action_id
    JOIN `acl_roles` ON acl_roles_actions.role_id = acl_roles.id
WHERE `role_id` in ('SOME_HASH', 'ANOTHER_HASH') AND `action_id` IN
 (SELECT `id` FROM `acl_actions` WHERE `category` LIKE '%SOMENAME%')
 GROUP BY ROLE_NAME
 ORDER BY ROLE_NAME, FIELD(acl_actions.name, "access", "delete", "edit", "export", "import", "list", "view")
 ;
```